# Check if hashtag is at the start OR middle of string php

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently grabbing all #hashtags found in a string (i.e. a tweet). Works as it should.

However, I want to find hashtags that are only at the start of the string OR in the MIDDLE of the string (or close enough to it). In other words, find all hashtags that aren't at the end of the string.

***Bonus points***, if you can also point me in the direction on how to see if a hashtag exists at the end of the string as well.

```
$tweet = 'This is an #example tweet';

preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/u', $tweet, $matches);  

if ($matches) { // found hashtag(s) }
```

Comment: Several hashtags at the start? Like [`'/\G(#\w+)[^\w#]*/u'`](https://regex101.com/r/sU1gR4/1)? Or just a single hashtag at the start, end and not at start/end of the string?

Comment: Assume that words and hastags are always separated by space?

Comment: i think to find "middle or close enough " you have to find length and apply regex on that area .what you expect on this   'This is an #example #badexample  tweet';

Comment: why you don't use `strpos` function?

Comment: For my usage, I don't need to know how many may exist at the start or in the middle. Just that one exists either at the start of the tweet or in the middle. In simpler terms, if a hashtag exists, but it's not at the end of the tweet, etc.

Comment: Use anchors `^` is the start of the string `$` is the end of the string. What are bonus points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Check if Hashtag is last word; the strpos and explode way:

$tweet = 'This is an #example #tweet';
$words = explode(" ", $tweet);
$last_word = end($words);

// count the number of times "#" occurs in the $tweet.
// if # exists in somewhere else $exists_anywhere equals TRUE !!
$exists_anywhere = substr_count($tweet,'#') > 1 ? TRUE : FALSE ;

if(strpos($last_word,'#') !== FALSE  ) {
   // last word has #
}
```

from doc :

> Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is
>   contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they
>   will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, but `tweet#` would not be a valid hashtag. I would need to look for something like `#tweet` at the end...

Comment: Can `end()` be exploded like that?

Comment: I'm sorry that was a typo.

Comment: That still wouldn't work. I think I can take it from here though, I'll edit your answer too. Thanks! :)

Comment: Also, can you add a method to check if a hashtag exists at the start or somewhere else besides the end? Just so the answer coincides with my question. :)

Comment: but you said : `In other words, find all hashtags that aren't at the end of the string.`

Comment: Yes, but you're code only looks for a hashtag at the end. Not if a hashtag exists anywhere else in the string.

Answer (score 1):

To match at the beginning only:

```
/^(#\w+)/
```

To look for a specific #hashtag:

```
/^#tweet/
```

To match anywhere in the middle (not beginning or end):

```
/^[^#]+(#\w+)[^\w]+$/
```

To look for a specific #hashtag:

```
/^[^#]+#tweet[^\w]$/
```

To match at the end only:

```
/(#\w+)$/
```

To look for a specific #hashtag:

```
/#tweet$/
```

Comment: I would need to look for something like `#tweet` at the end...would the end only look for `#` as the last character?

Comment: Edited.  Thought you were trying to find hashtags of unknown words at different positions.

Comment: I am...`#tweet` was just an example ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/(?!#\w+\W+$)(#\w+)\W/', $tweet, $result);
```

**This is a #tweet folks** will catch #tweet

**#Second example of #tweet folks** will catch `#Second` and `#tweet`

**#Another example of #tweet** will catch `#Another` but not `#tweet` (even if it ends in `!`, `.`, or any other non-word character)

**We're almost done, #yup!** won't catch anything

**Last one #tweet! good night** will catch `#tweet`

Of course, all your hastags (captures) will be stored in `$result[1]`

Answer (score 0):

OK, personally I would turn the string into an array of words:

```
$words = explode(' ', $tweet);
```

Then run a check on the first word:

```
preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/u', $words[0], $matches);
if ($matches) {
    //first word has a hashtag
}
```

Then you can simply walk through rest of array for hashtags in the middle.
And finally to check the last word,

```
$sizeof = count($words) - 1;
preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/u', $word[$sizeof], $matches);
if ($matches) {
    //last word has a hashtag
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE / EDIT**

```
$tweet = "Hello# It's #a# beaut#iful day. #tweet";
$tweet_arr = explode(" ", $tweet);
$arrCount = 0;

foreach ($tweet_arr as $word) {
    $arrCount ++;
    if (strpos($word, '#') !== false) {
        $end = substr($word, -1);
        $beginning = substr($word, 0, 1);
        $middle_string = substr($word, 1, -1);
        if ($beginning === "#") {
            echo "hash is at the beginning on word " . $arrCount . "<br />";
        }
        if (strpos($middle_string, '#') !== false) {
            $charNum = strpos($middle_string, '#') + 1;
            echo "hash is in the middle at character number " . $charNum . " on word " . $arrCount . "<br />";
        }
        if ($end === "#") {
            echo "hash is at the end on word " . $arrCount . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to look for something like #tweet at the end...would the end only look for # as the last character?

Comment: I added code ...  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, no, not exactly. `#tweet` was just an example. It could be ANY hashtag.

Comment: This code is complicated dude. Also, the `foreach` is always going to return a single word. Thanks for your help, but I choose another answer as it fit my needs perfectly. Cheers!